# Make an autoincrement field in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got a table in SQLite

```
create table table_dishes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    title text,
    price real,
    weight real,
    description text,
    position integer);
```

How to make field "position integer" autoincrement?

Comment: Check [THIS](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) out

Comment: why you need this?you can think position value is _id value or if you want not equal you can see that like _id + 1

Answer (score 1):

There is as such no autoincrement feature but they have added **ROWID** which is added automatically. So the  **integer primary key** which you will create for your table will point to this `ROWID`.

Also from the [SQLITE docs](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1):

> A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement.

Answer (score 0):

Per the SQLite documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1),

> Short answer: A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

insert value should be  like  : `(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(position), 0) + 1 FROM table_dishes)` for that column, every time you insert a new row into `table_dishes` table, if you decide to keep `position column as non-primary key`